# How to get a vertical bar which is longer than \mid ?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

sometimes when writing mathematical expression with partial derivatives, one needs to write a vertical bar afterwards and write the value at the which the partial derivatives are being computed as subscripts. See for example the bottom post here:

http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=63809

However, the \mid symbol doesn't produce a tall bar that corresponds to the size of the partial derivatives term. Is there a way to have a taller bar?

PS: Some other posts here mention \middle| but this doesn't compile on my computer.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222222/how-to-get-a-vertical-bar-which-is-the-exact-size-of-the-object

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try

```
\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{x_0}
```

Or if you have `\usepackage{amsmath}`, you can use `\rvert` instead of the `|`. In fact, this is probably the better way to go.

Comment: Thanks it works fine. I was using \rvert earlier also. My problem is that I used a custom partial derivative formulation from: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf  .This was causing problems with the size of the vertical bar following the partial derivatives.

Comment: 1 vote up for the elegant solution.

Comment: You can also use `\biggr` (or one of the other similar macros). As a side note, anyone (including the ISO) who thinks that _e_ should be typeset upright should probably just be ignored (modulo hard publishers' requirements). =)

Comment: `\rvert` and `|` are equivalent in this case because the class is ignored when a mathchar is used as a delimiter.

Comment: @Philipp: I meant better from a semantic point of view, but you're absolutely right. I'd probably be lazy and write `|` (in fact, I guess I was and I did =).

Comment: @TH. But the \biggr can't be used on its own. It must have a corresponding \biggl to start with.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: That is not true. Try it.

Comment: @TH. Yes you're indeed right. Thanks for pointing this out. I tried another funny example: \biggr ( x \bigl )  and LaTeX compiles it. I always thought that the r or l was denoting the right and left and that u can't have a r before the occurrence of an l.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: `\biggl` is a macro which expands to `\mathopen\bigg`. `\biggr` is a macro which expands to `\mathclose\bigg`. `\bigg` is a macro which takes one argument and expands to `\{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to14.5pt{}\right.\nulldelimiterspace 0pt\mathsurround 0pt$}}`. So basically, `\biggr)` results in `\mathclose{---\left)---\right.---}` where the `---` is just the rest of the TeX magic to get the spacing right and the height of the parenthesis right.

Comment: Note that `\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{x_0}` causes there to be an extra `\nulldelimiterspace` of blank space to the left of the fraction. (By default, `\nulldelimiterspace` is 1.2pt.) Depending on what's around this expression, it's either a good idea or not worth the trouble to remove that extra space.

Comment: see also my question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222222/how-to-get-a-vertical-bar-which-is-the-exact-size-of-the-object

Comment: `\rvert` also seems to need accompanying `\left` and `\right` commands to adjust its size as Ulrike Fischer mentioned in the answer below. Otherwise, it just produces a small letter sized bar.

Answer (score 23):

\middle should work in any current system. But it needs accompaigning \left+\right. Like braces in \left/right it will adapt its size to the size of the content:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}
$\left\{a\middle|a\right.$ 
$\left\{\int \middle|\int\right.$
$\int\mid \int$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes it works fine. Thanks for explaining how to use it.

Comment: `\middle` requires e-TeX, but as you say, any current system...

Comment: Yes it's ok with my TeXLive. 1 vote up for the explanation.

Comment: see also my question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222222/how-to-get-a-vertical-bar-which-is-the-exact-size-of-the-object