# How to get a \mid binary relation that grows

Tags: math-mode, symbols

This question relates to one about getting a vertical bar longer than `\mid`.

[How to get a vertical bar which is longer than \mid ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3137/how-to-get-a-vertical-bar-which-is-longer-than-mid)

However while the given `\middle|` solution works for me, it no longer behaves as a binary relation and so loses the space to the left-and-right of it that `\mid` puts in.

(I know I could manually add space, but I want the *right* way to do this.)

In fact I want a "growable `\mid`" that works like `\left\{` and its relatives.

Comment: Inserting space manually is fine. You can hide that in a macro, but you have to do it somewhere.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to get `\middle|` to behave exactly as `\mid` on all accounts (spacing, stacking in the form `\mid\mid`, etc.), you need to use `\mathrel{}` on both sides of `\middle|` (manual spaces like \; won't do the job correctly in all situations):

```
\newcommand{\relmiddle}[1]{\mathrel{}\middle#1\mathrel{}}
```

Here's a code that compares `\mid` and the new command `\relmiddle` on two different formulas and shows that the spacing is identical:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\relmiddle}[1]{\mathrel{}\middle#1\mathrel{}}
\begin{document}
\nulldelimiterspace=0pt% to kill the little space before \left and after \right (not a good idea in a real document)
$a \mid -b$\par
$\left. a \relmiddle| -b \right.$

$a \mid\mid -b$\par
$\left. a \relmiddle|\relmiddle| -b \right.$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks like _the_ solution!

Comment: Instead of typing `\relmiddle|\relmiddle|`, it may be better to type `\relmiddle\Vert`; the latter approach makes for slightly tighter (and probably more appropriate) spacing between the vertical bars. In fact, `\relmiddle\Vert` has the exact same look (and spacing properties) as does `\parallel`.

Answer (score 11):

(Edit: This answer was based on the mistaken assumption that the question was about a binary *operator*, not a *relation*. Philippe's answer is better for the latter, but it is not quite so easy if you want a binary operator that grows. See also the comments.)

My answer is like Will's (now gone), except a bit more elaborate:

```
\def\binmiddle#1{\mathchoice{\mskip\medmuskip}{\mskip\medmuskip}{}{}\middle#1
                 \mathchoice{\mskip\medmuskip}{\mskip\medmuskip}{}{}}
```

Explanation: A binary operator is surrounded by `\medmuskip` in display and text mode, but no space in script and scriptscript mode.

Comment: For those whose knowledge of Norwegian is even worse than mine (is that possible?), the command `\medmuskip` roughly translates as "with a stingy mouse".

Comment: @Harald Much better on both counts! Without looking up the values I can never remember when to use what.

Comment: You can avoid the `\mathchoice` by using `\nonscript`: `\nonscript\mskip\medmuskip`. But the solution isn't correct any more with LuaTeX, where the spacing around a Rel atom might be different front `\medmuskip`. I think Philippe's solution is both more robust (since it always works) and more idiomatic (you say what you want, not how to achieve it).

Comment: @Harald: a binary relation (`\mathrel`) like `mid` is surrounded by `\thickmuskip`; it's binary operations (`\mathbin`, like +, \times, etc.) which use `\medmuskip`. The difference is not really visible a lot, but can be in a context with strong inter-word stretching or shrinking (`\medmuskip` shrinks a lot but not `\thickmuskip`; here, that's not a real concern because there is no stretching/shrinking inside a \left...\right construct).

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I get the message … (sorry, I have been too busy to keep track lately). What happened is this: My brain latched onto the word “binary”, so I based my answer on the assumption that we were talking about binary operators, not relations – i.e., Bin objects, not Rel objects. Your answer is more appropriate for the latter, but mine is still the best I can come up with if the former is what is wanted. (In TeX, relations are binary, so we don't usually use that adjective with them. That is how the confusion arose.)

Comment: This does indeed grow, but it does so too much. Observe: `\begin{align} & \left\lbrace f \;\vert\; \ldots \right\rbrace \text{ versus} \\ & \left\lbrace f \;\middle\vert\; \ldots \right\rbrace \end{align}` (No linebreaks in comments is unfortunate, I know).

Comment: @kahen: I see no difference between your two samples. In general, however, I too often think that `\left` and `\right` delimiters tend to get a bit too large, so I often use one of the `\big` variants instead. I expect the same would go for `\middle`. (But I have not yet felt the need for it myself, so I lack experience with that.)

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen I figured it out. It's a problem with `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}`