# \middle uses spacing as if it were regular size even when it's \bigg

Tags: math-mode

Following the lead of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5550/1495) and the interface of `mathtools.sty's` `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro, I've made a `\setof<*|[<size>]|>#1#2` that uses setbuilder notation for a set.  But I cannot for the life of me understand why the third setbuilder lines up with the first one rather than the second one.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\mathcrel#1{\mathrel{}#1\mathrel{}}
\def\midrel#1{\mathcrel{\middle#1}}
\let\setbuilder|
\def\setof{%
  \@ifstar
    \setof@S
    {\@ifnextchar[%]
      \setof@B
      \setof@N}}
\def\setof@S#1#2{\left\lbrace #1 \midrel\setbuilder #2 \right\rbrace}
\def\setof@B[#1]#2#3{\mathopen #1\lbrace #2 \mathcrel{#1\setbuilder} #3 \mathclose #1\rbrace}
\def\setof@N#1#2{\lbrace #1 \mathcrel\setbuilder #2\rbrace}
\makeatother

\def\CC{\mathbf C}\def\NN{\mathbf N}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\ell^\infty &= \setof{(x_n) \in \CC^\NN}{\sup_{n\in\NN} |x_n| < \infty}. \\
\ell^\infty &= \setof[\bigg]{(x_n) \in \CC^\NN}{\sup_{n\in\NN} |x_n| < \infty}. \\
\ell^\infty &= \setof*{(x_n) \in \CC^\NN}{\sup_{n\in\NN} |x_n| < \infty}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The spacing is excessive: `\def\mathcrel#1{\mathrel{#1}}` and `\def\midrel#1{\nonscript\;\middle#1\nonscript\;}` are sufficient.

Comment: Just change `\mathcrel` to `\def\mathcrel#1{\mathrel{}\mathclose{}#1\mathopen{}\mathrel{}}`. That's necessary because, with your code, `#1` might not be a relation so you must kill the spacing using mathopen/mathclose. @egreg: what you propose will not always give the same spacing as a mathrel.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet Why not? It *is* a `\mathrel` no matter what `#1` is.

Comment: @egreg: `\mathcrel` yes, but not `\midrel`.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet It depends on which contexts it's used. The vertical bar in the set notation should *always* be surrounded by thick spaces (in text or display style), so it's not really a relation in TeXnical sense.

Comment: @egreg: in that case, you should be using `\def\mathcrel#1{\nonscript\;\mathclose{}#1\mathopen{}\nonscript\;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the second two lines line up if you change the definition to

```
 \def\midrel#1{\mathcrel{{}\middle#1{}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\setof[2]\lbrace\rbrace{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,#2}
```

or similar spacing around the `\vert`

Comment: As much as I like `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` I'm trying to move away from it because it does "wrong" things such as this: `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert \def\amsabs#1{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert} \[ \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)| \text{ versus } \sup_{y\in Y} \abs{f(y)} \text{ versus } \sup_{z \in Z} \amsabs{f(z)} \]` - it kills the spacing between the modulus and the "sup".

Comment: As it should, the space produced by `\sub\bigl(` and `\sub\left(` should be the same for consistency. Besides `|...|` is wrong anyways `\lvert-1\rvert \neq |-1|`

Comment: I agree that `|...|` is wrong, but it's still the case that `$\sup_{z\in Z} \left\lvert f(z)\right\rvert$` produces a small space between the modulus and the "sup" and the same thing made with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` doesn't and that just looks wrong to me

Comment: That is not `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`s fault, it is `\left` not producing an opening fence. In `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` we make sure it does produce something that validates as an opening fence.