# Why don't the curly braces and the mid bar become bigger?

Tags: amsmath, braces

I'm having the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb K}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
l^2 = \{x \doteqdot (x_n)_n \in \K^{\N_0}\mid \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\abs{x_n}^2 < +\infty\}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

I'd like the curly braces and the `mid` bar to become bigger (they should have the same height as the sum), but they don't want to enlarge.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Use `\left\{` and `\right\}` for the first part. I dunno about the `\mid` :-) Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12773/32374

Comment: @darthbith `\middle`.

Comment: @darthbith: Thanks, I thought I should use `\left{`, but of course that didn't work. You thus solved the first part of my question!

Comment: @Jeroen `\left\{ A \middle| B \right\}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't rely on `\left`, `\middle`, and `\right` (since they produce "fences" that are *too large* for the equation at hand). Instead, I suggest using `\biggl\{`, `\biggm|`, and `\biggr\}`. Observe that the spacing around the `\biggm|` symbol is the same as for the small `\mid` symbol.

For more on when *not* to use automatically-sized fences see, e.g., [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001).

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb K}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
l^2 = \biggl\{ x \doteqdot (x_n)_n \in \K^{\N_0} \biggm| 
          \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\abs{x_n}^2 < +\infty \biggr\}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: From the point of view of LaTeX design philosophy, rather than engage in quasi-visual formatting by using macros such as `\biggl\{`, `\biggm|`, and `\biggr\}` directly in one's code, it's far better to set up macros named, say, `\Set` and `\given`, which define the look of a "set" (curly braces...) and of the symbol that indicates conditioning information (a vertical bar). It's straightforward to do so with the tools of the [mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package (pun intended; see p. 26 of the user guide). Observe that a line break is permitted after the `\given` symbol. (No screenshot is provided since the resulting is the same as the one shown above; it's just the input syntax that's quite different and, I would claim, much easier to parse.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % mathtools loads amsmath in the background
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert} % a modified definition of \abs
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb K}

%% See p. 26 of the user guide of the mathtools package for the next few macros
\providecommand\given{}  % just to make sure it exists
\newcommand\SetSymbol[1][]{\nonscript\:#1\vert\nonscript\:\allowbreak}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[1]\lbrace\rbrace{%
  \renewcommand\given{\SetSymbol[\delimsize]}#1}

\begin{document}
\[
l^2 = \Set[\bigg]{ x \doteqdot (x_n)_n \in \K^{\N_0} \given
                   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\abs{x_n}^2 < +\infty }
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: Mico is referring to the very latest version of the `mathtools` manual, corresponding to version 1.14. The syntax is also very useful for probabilities with build in support for conditionals. (though in this case I usually do not use an external macro for the `\given` symbol)

Comment: In general a lot can actually be done to hide away especially stuff that are only of typographic importance, and thus getting a source code much closer to the actual meaning of the mathematical expression.

Answer (score 2):

For braces, you want to use `\left\{` and `\right\}` ... the brace itself still needs to be escaped.

The middle conditional bar can be given with the newcommand `\relmiddle` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5550/47522).

For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N} %Natuurlijke getallen
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb K} %Reële of complexe getallen

\newcommand{\relmiddle}[1]{\mathrel{}\middle#1\mathrel{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
l^2 = \left\{x \doteqdot (x_n)_n \in \K^{\N_0} \relmiddle|  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\abs{x_n}^2 < +\infty\right\}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image: equation]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The middle bar is bigger now, but the spacing before and behind it is gone. I'd like to get it back. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: @Jeroen Perhaps also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5502/how-to-get-a-mid-binary-relation-that-grows for a new command that solves the problem in probably the best way possible... answer edited to match.

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from the  `mathtools` package. I also use `xparse` to have a very simple syntax: the set of x such that P(x) is typeset with a `\Set{x;P(x)}` command. For a fine tuning of the delimiter size, you can use `\set`with an optional argument:  `\big`, `\Big` , `\bigg` or `\Bigg`.

I also recall a definition of `\abs` and `norm` as defined in the  mathtools`documentation. They have an optional argument, and therere is  sim![enter image description here][1]ilarly an`Abs`and a`\Norm` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb K}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}%% variable sized absolute value
\def\Abs{\abs*}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}%% variable sized norm
\def\Norm{\norm*}

\usepackage{xparse}
%
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]{\{}{\}}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1} {#1\,\delimsize|\,#2}}%{#1\:;\:#2}
\def\Set{\set*}%

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
 \begin{tabular}{r >{$\displaystyle}l<{$}}%
\verb+ \Set, \Abs+ : &l^2 = \Set{x \doteqdot (x_n)_n \in \K^{\N_0} ; \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Abs{x_n}^2 < +\infty} \\
\verb+ \set, \abs+ : & l^2 = \set{x \doteqdot (x_n)_n \in \K^{\N_0} ; \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\abs{x_n^2} < +\infty} \\
\verb+ \set[\big]+ : & l^2 = \set[\big]{x \doteqdot (x_n)_n \in \K^{\N_0} ; \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\abs[big]{x_n}^2 < +\infty} \\
\verb+ \set[\Big]+ : & l^2 = \set[\Big]{x \doteqdot (x_n)_n \in \K^{\N_0} ; \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\abs[\Big]{x_n}^2 < +\infty} \\
\verb+ \set[\bigg]+ : & l^2 = \set[\bigg]{x \doteqdot (x_n)_n \in \K^{\N_0} ; \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\abs[\bigg]{x_n}^2 < +\infty} \\
\verb+ \set[\Bigg]+ : & l^2 = \set[\Bigg]{x \doteqdot (x_n)_n \in \K^{\N_0} ; \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\abs[\Bigg]{x_n}^2 < +\infty} \\
 & \Set{\Abs{\dfrac{a}{b}}}_{b\neq 0}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: you're right, it was just to give a feeling how it works. I correct the typo at once.