# Redefine \middle| to insert space before and after itself

Tags: spacing, brackets, syntax

I want to use \middle| inside of brackets like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \left\{\frac{1}{n} \middle| n>0\right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

\end{document}
```

But this examples lacks space before and after the mid |. I don't want to write every time:

```
left\{\frac{1}{n} \;\middle|\; n>0\right\}
```

How can I redefine the \middle| command to mean \;\middle|\;?
I tried

```
\edef{\middle|}{\,\middle|\,}
```

and

```
\let\originalmiddle\middle
\renewcommand{\middle}{\;\originalmiddle\;}
```

but neither works. 
What is the difference between both commands and why do they not work with \middle?

Comment: Maybe you just want `\mid`? Though, that won't scale vertically.

Comment: I want the middle command to scale vertically like \middle| does.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5502 to get `\middle|` to behave exactly as `\mid`

Comment: Thx for hint, I used your suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The symbol needs to come after the `\middle` so

```
\let\originalmiddle\middle
\renewcommand{\middle}[1]{\;\originalmiddle#1\;}
```

Although redefining primitives always breaks something, somewhere so I would suggest instead

```
\newcommand{\xmiddle}[1]{\;\middle#1\;}
```

and use `\xmiddle` (or any other name you wish)

Comment: Wow thx, that was fast! 
I tried to play around with a parameter but somehow did not manage to get things right.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know how would one do that with a `\(U)delcode` or `\(U)delimiter`? (i.e., without `\middle`?)

Comment: @morbusg If I understand your comment correctly, I don't think you can

Comment: I mean, if I wouldn't have `\left...\right`, but instead `\bigl...\bigr`, then `\middle` wouldn't work; but as the `|` is also defined as a delimiter, one can do `\big|`, but that isn't a class relation symbol then. I was wondering if that could be made a relation.

Comment: @morbusg `\bigm|`?

Comment: @morbusg \bigm \Biggm and friends are defined already to be relation just as \bigr is \mathopen

Comment: @Manuel, David: Oooh! I didn't know that! Thanks!

Comment: `\newcommand{\relmiddle}{\nonscript\;\middle\nonscript\;}`