# How to get a \mid binary relation that grows in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex

Same question as this one: [How to get a \mid binary relation that grows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5502/how-to-get-a-mid-binary-relation-that-grows), except in luatex.

The answer to the question in pdflatex is to use `\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{}`, which produces too much space on the right when compiled with `lualatex`.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

  Consider the expression: $\left(a\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{}b\right)$.
  Compile this with `pdflatex` and `lualatex` and compare spacing.

\end{document}
```

**Compiled with lualatex/ pdflatex:**

[image]

Is this a bug and/or how do I fix this?  I'm using texlive 2017.

**Edit:**  I asked this question on the LuaTeX mailing list and got some interesting replies.  In particular: http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2017-November/006645.html.  While editing this `egreg` updated his answer with a solution based on the linked email ;-)

Comment: It seems that LuaTeX inserts an empty atom between `\middle|` and `\mathrel{}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I compile the simpler

```
$\left(a\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{}b\right)\showlists$\showlists
```

I get the following in the log file

```
\mathinner
.\leftheight=0.00052 depth=0.00256 class=172 "28300
.\mathord
..\fam1 a
.\mathrel
..{}
.\middleheight=0.00682 depth=0.00638 "26A30C
.\mathrel
..{}
.\mathord
..\fam1 b
.\right"29301
```

which seems OK, but is translated into boxes and glue as

```
\mathon
\hbox(7.5+2.5)x28.46626, direction TLT
.\hbox(7.5+2.5)x3.8889, direction TLT
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (
.\OML/cmm/m/it/10 a
.\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
.\hbox(7.5+2.5)x2.77779, direction TLT
..\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 j
.\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
.\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
.\OML/cmm/m/it/10 b
.\hbox(7.5+2.5)x3.8889, direction TLT
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )
\mathoff
```

There is a mysterious box which causes *two* `\thickmuskip` glues to be inserted.

Solution:

```
$\left(a\mathrel{}\middle|\mathopen{}\mathrel{}b\right)$
```

which works also with `pdflatex`.

[image]

### Addendum

As explained by Hans on the thread starting at http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2017-November/006642.html at the luatex mailing list, there is a simpler workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\relmiddle}{\Umiddle class 5 }

\begin{document}

$\left(a \relmiddle| b\right)$

$(a\mid b)$

\end{document}
```

The class numbers to be used are different from the standard math classes in legacy TeX (section 7.1.3.3.1 in the LuaTeX manual):

```
 0  ord
 1  op normal
 2  op limits
 3  op no limits
 4  bin
 5  rel
 6  open
 7  close
 8  punct
 9  inner
10  under
11  over
12  vcenter
```

[image]

We can make it work with the other engines by doing

```
\documentclass{article}

\ifdefined\Umiddle
  \newcommand{\relmiddle}{\Umiddle class 5 }
\else
  \newcommand{\relmiddle}[1]{\mathrel{}\middle#1\mathrel{}}
\fi

\begin{document}

$\left(a \relmiddle| b\right)$

$(a\mid b)$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me.  Do you know if it is a bug or intended behavior?  I reported this to the luatex mailing list but it seems mostly dead (judging from the archives.)  Do you happen to know if there is a better place to report this so that it gets fixed if it's a bug?

Comment: @1k5 Added a better workaround based on Hans's suggestions on the luatex list.

Comment: I was just editing my question to add Hans' solution ;-)  Thanks, you made it more elegant than what I would have.