# How to build this formula in Latex?

Tags: math-mode

[image]

I'm just trying to build the formula shown below in Latex. My approach would be the following: `prob[ \tilde{n}=n \mid \tilde{s}=s]`
However, the first two `n`'s are not displayed correctly. Does anyone know what is wrong about my approach? (absolute Latex beginner)

Comment: `$\operatorname{prob}[\tilde{n} = n \mid \tilde{s} = n] = p > \frac{1}{2}$` with package `amsmath` ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6gew.png)).

Comment: What's wrong with your `n`s?  The formula you've given is different than your attempt.  Also, it's helpful if you give a complete minimal working example with your code, that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `end{document}`.

Answer (score 21):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\prob{prob}
\begin{document}
\(
\prob[\tilde{n}=n\mid\tilde{s}=n] =p > \frac{1}{2}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response, that really helps me a lot!

Comment: The OP is using the correct `\tilde{n}` syntax; while `\tilde n` also works it's worse markup.

Comment: @egreg I find this highly subjective.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Then try `$\tilde\notin$`.

Comment: @egreg I’m not sure what this is supposed to show me: at any rate, `\tilde\notin` and `\tilde{\notin}` render identically, as expected.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Try *without* `amsmath`. It's just an example, though, which shows that *something* can go wrong with the sloppy syntax.

Comment: @egreg So amsmath fixes a bug/bad API in the (`\mathaccent`) command: The syntax isn’t sloppy, it’s well-defined through TeX’ rules (and the original `\tilde` breaks this expectation, and hence required fixing).

Comment: @KonradRudolph `amsmath` fixes no bug, it just reimplements all the math accents. Since the original `\tllde` command has *no* argument, the syntax `\tilde x` is *not* well defined. Look at page 291 of the TeXbook for the syntax of `\mathaccent` and page 289 for `<math field>` to discover why `\tilde\notin` fails.

Comment: Why does this simple answer get 17 votes?  Sometimes, I don't understand the psychology of this site...but I'm not complainin'

Comment: @Steven: It's probably because the question showed up in the "Hot Network Questions" list for some reason, so it is getting a lot of traffic.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for pointing that out (in all my years here, my mind blanks out that part of the webpage...I'm not even aware it exists!)  I'll remember that, next time I need to apply a thumb to the scales. `;^)`

Answer (score 12):

With a code adapted from an example in `mathtools` documentation. The `\prob` macro can make the size of the brackets and  midrule fit the contents of the macro using the  starred version `\prob*`. Alternatively one can use an optional argument: `\big, \Big, \bigg,\Bigg`, which inserts a pair of implicit `\bigl ... \bigr` before the delimiters:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\providecommand\given{}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\prob[1]{\mathrm{prob}}[]{}{
\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\:\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\mathopen{}}
#1}

\begin{document} %

\[ \prob[\big]{\tilde{n} = n\given\tilde{s} = n} = p > \mfrac12\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

An alternative that sizes the brackets and the vertical bar automatically to the content between them is to use `\left`, `\middle` and `\right`.  This uses [egreg’s trick for a vertical bar that grows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401234/how-to-get-a-mid-binary-relation-that-grows-in-luatex).

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareMathOperator\prob{prob}

\ifdefined\Umiddle
  \newcommand{\relmiddle}{\Umiddle class 5 }
\else
  \newcommand{\relmiddle}[1]{\mathrel{}\middle#1\mathrel{}}
\fi

\begin{document}
\(
\prob \left[ \tilde{n} = \frac{n^{2^m}}{2} \relmiddle\vert \tilde{s} = n \right] = p > \frac{1}{2}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Equation]

This example will work with your font packages of choice, not just `unicode-math`. And you can still declare `\prob` with two arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me very well even though [Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427986/48478) has a perfect answer.  I have changed `n` to `n/2` for better visibility on the height of the mid line.

```
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{prob} \left[\left. \tilde{n}=\frac{n}{2}  \right| \tilde{s}=n\right] =p > \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
```

[image]
I have added `\left.`  before the `fraction` to enforce the height of the mid line to be that of the height of the fraction.

Comment: Please do never use `$$` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: @TeXnician Corrected. Thanks for the reference

Comment: iom the vertical bar and the `[...]` should be the same size as they are part of a combined syntax