# How to make \mid longer?

Tags: symbols

I have the following expression

```
$$\left\{\varphi\in\text{End}\left({\widetilde{E}/\overline{\F}_{\Pf}}\right)\mid \varphi\text{Frob}_{\Pf}=\text{Frob}_{\Pf}\varphi\right\}$$
```

and would like to know how to match the length of `\mid` to the length of `\left\{` and `\right\}`. Thanks!

Comment: Use `\,\middle\vert\,`

Comment: You cannot, `\mid` is not a fence it is a binary symbol. I would also suggest making a macro for sets and thus hide the vertical line inside the macro. Then it is also easier to change syntax later on instead of having to do a lot of search and replace. (personally I tend to use `mathtools` to build such a set macro).

Comment: and please don't use `\text` for operators, use say `\operatorname` for once of, ot define `\End`. `\text` does not give you what you would expect in an italic context.

Comment: @daleif I did use \operatorname but I fear that people wouldn't understand \End and \Frob.

Comment: In your formula, `\left(` and `\right)` should be `(` and `)`; increasing the size to cover the tilde is wrong. Then also the outer braces can be normal size or, if you really want them larger, `\bigl\{` and `\bigr\}`; you can then use `\bigm|` for the middle bar.

Comment: Duplicate(s): [Variable-sized “such that” pipe](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32051/5764); [How to get a vertical bar which is longer than `\mid`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3137/5764)

Comment: Regarding your use of `$$`, see [Why is `\[` …`\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: @yanbo that is of course why you should always post full copy'n'paste directly compilable minimal examples

Comment: @GonzaloMedina your command is like a magic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For middle stretchable delimiters you can use `\middle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\F{F}
\newcommand\Pf{Pf}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Frob}{Frob}

\begin{document}

\[
\left\{\varphi\in\End
\bigl(\widetilde{E}/\overline{\F}_{\Pf}\bigr)
\,\middle\vert\, 
\varphi\Frob_{\Pf}=\Frob_{\Pf}\varphi\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also the use of `\DeclareMathOperator` to produce the right font and spacing for "End" and "Frob". Also, `$$...$$` shouldn't be used in modern LaTeX documents; use `\[...\]` instead. Since I didn't know the definitions of some commands, I defined them provisionally.

Comment: The horizontal spacing of using `\,\middle\vert\,` is not the same as using `\mid`

Answer (score 4):

For completeness here is the one I normally use

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[2]{\{}{\}}{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,#2}
```

---

Edit 2014. After using `\Set{A}{B}` for some time, this syntax is not particularly natural, too far from the actual meaning. Instead I'm now using this

```
\providecommand\given{} % is redefined in \Set
\newcommand\SetSymbol[1][]{\nonscript\:#1\vert\nonscript\:}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[1]{\{}{\}}{
  \renewcommand\given{\SetSymbol[\delimsize]}
  #1
}
```

Now we can simply use

```
\Set{ x\in A \given x^2 > 1 }
```

much much closer to the mathematical meaning.

I use the `\SetSymbol` because there are very complicated set constructions, where one cannot use `\Set` (`\{` and `\}` on separate lines), and thus in that case one may want to be able to refer to the *given* symbol for sets, just in case one want change the symbol later on.