# Context sensitive set formation operator

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

In my  works I normally use

```
\{x\mid\varphi(x)\}
```

as a set forming operator. Its disadvantage, from my point of view, is that the vertical stroke is always the same, irrespective of the context. Is there any package that would make `\mid` context sensitive? In the sense that when I for example use

```
\Bigl\{x\mid\varphi\}\Bigr
```

the height of `\mid` is adjusted to the height of the brackets? If not, could you please give me a hint how can I define it to work in this way?

Comment: There's plenty of material on the subject on the site. Anyway, `\Bigl\{x\Bigm|\varphi\Bigr\}` will do

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot. But what about displayed formulas? BTW, I asked the question because I had not been able to find anything (which only means that I hadn't delved deep enough, it seems).

Comment: `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\set[1]{\lbrace}{\rbrace}{\def\given{\mathrel{}\mathclose{}\delimsize|\mathopen{}\mathrel{}}#1}` and then use `\set{x\given\phi}`, `\set[\big]{x\given\phi}`, `\set[\Big]{x\given\phi}`, `\set[\bigg]{x\given\phi}`, `\set[\Bigg]{x\given\phi}`, `\set*{x\given\phi}`.

Comment: Here is the construction I tend to recommend to my users: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125024/3929, it hides the actual set builder symbol in `\given` such that if you later on decide of a different symbol, you only have to change it once, no search'n'replace

Comment: @manuel, might be an idea to make your version allow a line break after the `|` (my version does)

Comment: @daleif Yes, I know, I just did it from memory now, so I didn't remember if I used `\allowbreak` or other thing. The name `\given` I took from you, I used `\st` before.