# How to get a vertical bar which is the exact size of the object?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, fractions, mathtools

I wish to use two vertical bars to sandwich a whole object:

[image]

What I found is that

> (Failure 1) if I use usual \mid or \rvert or |, it is **too small**.

[image]

> (Failure 2) if I use usual \left| or \right|, it is **too big** (due to that the unequal sizes of the numerator and the denominator).

[image]

> (Failure 3) if I use usual \left| or \right| on the numerator and the denominator separately, even though the size is correct, the the | is not connected. I wish to have | | sandwich from the outside. I wish **to have the whole bar connected from the numerator to the denominator**.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    \documentclass[aps]{revtex4} 
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \begin{document}
    $${\frac{  S }{  \overset{N}{\underset{{a=1}}{  \sum}}  T_a  } } $$

    $$\left|  {\frac{  S }{  \overset{N}{\underset{{a=1}}{  \sum}} T_a   } } \right| $$

$$\lvert \mid |  {\frac{  S }{  \overset{N}{\underset{{a=1}}{  \sum}}  T_a  } } | \mid \rvert$$

$${\frac{  \left|  S  \right| }{ \left|   \overset{N}{\underset{{a=1}}{  \sum}} T_a \right|   } }$$

    \end{document}
```

Is there a better way to fix this problem? Many thanks. Comments are welcome.

Comment: here is a related post, but the answer does not solve my issue: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3137/how-to-get-a-vertical-bar-which-is-longer-than-mid

Comment: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: I tried \[ ... \] just now, but the size is still incorrect. The output is like my Failure 2.

Comment: Check out `\delimitershortfall`. For instance [`mathmode.pdf`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode)

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try with `\vline`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
Your attempt

\[\left|\frac{S}{\sum\limits^{N}_{a=1}T_{a}}\right|\]

With \verb|\vline|

\[\vline\,\frac{S}{\sum\limits^{N}_{a=1}T_{a}}\,\vline\]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Some remarks:

1. Use `\[...\]\` instead of `$$`. See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/27635)
2. Use `\limits` instead of `\overset` and `\underset` to obtain subscripts and superscrips as in `\displaystyle`.

Answer (score 6):

Suddenly I realize what you want

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        $\frac{\displaystyle S}{\displaystyle\sum_{a=1}^NT_a}$
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```